# Ignite cache store behaviour

Tags: caching, ignite

I have persistent cache store 
When I put data into the cache, I see in logs that datastore put operation can be called on any cluster node

Is it correct behavior? 
I ask because I expect that put to the datastore should be called on the same node where put into the cache occurred.

Comment: Sergey, what is literal log message?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct for `ATOMIC` caches which update persistence store from primary nodes. `TRANSACTIONAL` cache, on the other hand, will update from the node that runs the transaction. This way it's possible to maintain underlying DB transaction to maintain full consistency between cache and DB.